# Getting: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' while trying to run an NLP classification model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

Trying follow code to run but getting AttributeError:

```
# Vectorize training and testing data
def Vectorize(vec, X_train, X_test):    
    
    X_train_vec = vec.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_vec = vec.transform(X_test)
    
    print('Vectorization complete.\n')
    
    return X_train_vec, X_test_vec

# Use multiple classifiers and grid search for prediction
def ML_modeling(models, params, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):    
    
    if not set(models.keys()).issubset(set(params.keys())):
        raise ValueError('Some estimators are missing parameters')

    for key in models.keys():
    
        model = models[key]
        param = params[key]
        gs = GridSearchCV(model, param, cv=5, error_score=0, refit=True)
        gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = gs.predict(X_test)
        
        # Print scores for the classifier
        print(key, ':', gs.best_params_)
        print("Precision: %1.3f \tRecall: %1.3f \t\tF1: %1.3f\n" % (precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'), recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'), f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
    
    return

models = {
    'Naive Bayes': GaussianNB()
}

params = {
    'Naive Bayes': { 'alpha': [0.5, 1], 'fit_prior': [True, False] }
}



# Train-test split and vectorize

X_train_vec, X_test_vec = Vectorize(TfidfVectorizer(), train["Abstract"], test["Abstract"])

ML_modeling(models, params, X_train_vec, X_test_vec, train.Include, test.Include)
```

Trying to run an NLP classification model (TFIDF)a. But getting Attribute error.

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
43 # Train-test split and vectorize
44 # X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['text'], df['category'], test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
---> 45 X_train_vec, X_test_vec = Vectorize(TfidfVectorizer(), train["Abstract"], test["Abstract"])
46
47 ML_modeling(models, params, X_train_vec, X_test_vec, train.Include, test.Include)

in Vectorize(vec, X_train, X_test)
4 def Vectorize(vec, X_train, X_test):
5
----> 6     X_train_vec = vec.fit_transform(X_train)
7     X_test_vec = vec.transform(X_test)
8

Data after preprocessing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB69a.jpg)

How to get rid of this attribute error?

Comment: You haven't showed the code where lower is actually being called, but you're passing a list where you should be passing a string. Look at your training data.

Comment: So I should pass X_train.astype(str) ?

Comment: No, it's not a problem you can fix by casting. You need to figure out why you're passing a list instead of a string.

Comment: I don't have any answer so far. Can you please tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: You would need to show your actual input data, `train["Abstract"]`.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the dataset, please take a look.

Comment: Uh, I'm not really sure I understand that, but it looks like you have a list strings. You probably want to convert that to a string with `' '.join(words)` or something. I suggest you look more closely at example code.